# Will the Credential Management API now available in Chrome 51 be widely adopted?

Tags: authentication, passwords, password-management, chrome

Google Chrome 51 stable includes support for the [Credential Management API](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/04/credential-management-api?hl=en). This implementation is based on the [W3C spec](http://w3c.github.io/webappsec-credential-management/).

Will other browsers support this technology (particularly Safari)?

Will web applications and native apps implement support?

Are there security concerns?

Comment: The first two questions are probably out of scope. The biggest security concern is the very existance of new APIs. New complex code loaded with features inevitably leads to bugs...

Answer (score 1):

With all new browser recommendations and drafts it is really hard to tell. But in it's current state it is unlikely to be widely adopted anytime soon.

- For starters this is a draft. Not a standard. Nothing is finalized
  and subject to be changed or dropped altogether. This is the biggest
  reason vendors will not be rushing to implement it.
- The next step is to become a recommendation. Becoming a W3C recommendation is what most vendors consider becoming a standard. But keep in mind it is still a recommendation. A vendor is not enforced to implement it. And all major browsers for one reason or another have rejected recommendations before.
- If it becomes accepted for implementation there is no telling how long it actually becomes implemented. WebRTC for example was first introduced in 2011. But modern browsers didn't start adapting it until 2013-14 at the earliest. Many others such as Safari didn't get it into development branches until this year.
- It also risks being beaten out for something better. As mentioned It isn't uncommon for it to take years for a recommendation to be
  implemented. And it could be possible something new is proposed and the CM API becomes deprecated before it hits the stable branch of other vendors. A reason for this is a browser rolls out their own "standard" which other vendors wish to adopt. Or a glaring security flaw is found that sets it back or potentially tarnishes its reputation.